# Finding all elements with a scroll

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scroll, protractor

What is the most reliable and efficient way to find all elements having a scroll on a page?

---

Currently, I'm thinking about using [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) with [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) comparing the `height` and `scrollHeight` attribute values:

```
element.all(by.xpath("//*")).filter(function (elm) {
    return protractor.promise.all([
        elm.getAttribute("height"),
        elm.getAttribute("scrollHeight")
    ]).then(function (heights) { 
        return heights[1] > heights[0];
    });
});
```

But I'm not sure about the correctness and performance of this approach.

Comment: Using vanilla JS you can do something like this `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter(function(el){‌​return el.offsetHeight !== el.scrollHeight})` but if you execute it on this page you see some elements without scrollbars so it's not reliable I think. Just wanted to comment this, I have no concrete answer (yet).

Comment: @AndrewTempleton don't worry, will review and decide on bounties today. And thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works with both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. The trick is detecting BOTH the too-wide/too-short AND if the computed CSS is going to allow you to display a scrollbar.

```
var ElementsWithScrolls = (function() {
    var getComputedStyle = document.body && document.body.currentStyle ? function(elem) {
        return elem.currentStyle;
    } : function(elem) {
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
    };

    function getActualCss(elem, style) {
        return getComputedStyle(elem)[style];
    }

    function isXScrollable(elem) {
        return elem.offsetWidth < elem.scrollWidth &&
            autoOrScroll(getActualCss(elem, 'overflow-x'));
    }

    function isYScrollable(elem) {
        return elem.offsetHeight < elem.scrollHeight &&
            autoOrScroll(getActualCss(elem, 'overflow-y'));
    }

    function autoOrScroll(text) {
        return text == 'scroll' || text == 'auto';
    }

    function hasScroller(elem) {
        return isYScrollable(elem) || isXScrollable(elem);
    }
    return function ElemenetsWithScrolls() {
        return [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'), hasScroller);
    };
})();

ElementsWithScrolls();
```

Comment: Hello, there is a typo on line 29, it should be ElementsWithScrolls

Answer (score 2):

It will select the elements with overflowed and non-overflowed scrolls inside body tag:

```
$('body *').filter(function() {
     return ($(this).scrollTop() != 0 || $(this).css('overflow') == 'scroll');
});
```